# ubuntu fails to start gnome

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, boot

I ran into a strange problem today, when i started my computer running Ubuntu 9, i got the loading screen and after that i got a black screen with the mouse and hourglass loading.
and it stays there, and doesn't load the gnome desktop.

I tried to go into recovery mode and it works. but don't know how to fix it to start the normal mode as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be corrupted ~/.gnome* files or other ~/.?* ("dot files").

Try logging in as a different user (create a new user account for the purpose if necessary).

Then try the following from recovery mode or a text console:

```
mkdir ~/BAD && mv ~/.?* ~/BAD
```

... this will create a directory and, if that was successful, it will move all of the "dot files" thereto (and thus out of your home directory).

Do NOT use ~/.* ... this might cause issues (not with GNU `mv` but with other systems) if it attempts to move .. (the parent of your home directory).  Technically ./.?* would fail to match files named things like .a and .b --- any dot followed by a single character.  As a practical matter I've never seen such a file used for any sort of configuration settings, so it's merely a theoretical issue for you to understand.  Depending on your shell you could use `mv ~/.[^.] ~/.?* ~/BAD/` to be pedantically comprehensive.

Comment: I wouldn't move everything at first. Just move the .gconf and .gnome2 and see if that solves the problem.

Comment: you were right. but what i did is login as root and did a reboot from console and it fixit.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your X config is messed up.

Have a look at [thie site](http://www.brunolinux.com/06-Fine_Tuning_Your_System/Configure_X.html) for re-configuring X.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of graphics driver are you running?  Recent update on the kernel or driver?  I use Fedora 11 + proprietary NVIDIA drivers on my desktop, and with every  kernel update I get to reconfig the binary driver over and over.

Please post more HW configuration information.